# Upload opencms project on real server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, opencms

I'm working on an open source java cms that name is opencms .
it is war file that you deploy it with tomcat and when it's up you go to localhost:8080/opencms and start to configure it as you want.
my problem is that when I've done my all jobs and making a cms  site with it, what I must do to upload it on a real server ?
do I have to make war file from it then upload it or just i upload it's deployed folder to server tomcat ?
and what i must do with it's database ? it's enough to export a .sql file from my local database and execute it on server database or i must do some other things ?
please help me
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an opencms installation on your "real" server that fits the one you created your page with.

It should be possible to just copy the content of opencms webapp folder inside tomcat to the tomcat on the target machine and also transfer copies of the associated databases to the "real" server.

Personally I prefer performing a standard installation of opencms on the target machine and configuring it (remove example content, change passwords, etc.).
Then I would use the export functionality of opencms to export the content on the development machine and import it into the target opencms instance.
The complexity depends on how much changes you have applied to the default installation - if you have developed your own modules, then it might be a bit more difficult.

Comment: thank's for your complete answer , so you say it's better to install a new clean opencms with it's installation on real server then i export my local version and then import it to real one? am i right ? if i export my local version does it export it's database data also ?

Comment: it exports all "cms content" - if you have done something additional with the database, then this might need some extra handling. To check if the export was complete you could also install a second "development instance" of opencms in a local virtual machine. By doing this you can also use it as a safe training area for setting up the real server. I would also suggest to study all opencms related stuff here on stackoverflow and also the archives of the opencms mailing list to get more infos

Comment: thank's again,and an other maybe Irrelevant question, did you work with jahia too ?it's seems really good and I wonder to know if it is better than opencms ? why?

Comment: today i install and work with , i find opencms better and more powerfull than it